# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str) in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm programming an app, which lets you store the info you provide to a listbox, which can be also used to print the data somewhere. (Create a txt with it stored.) I also tried all the advice from previous users posts, but couldn't find my case. Any help appreciated.

For some reason im getting the error you see in the title.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import*
from os import open

def addData():
    dataInsert = dataEntry.get()
    itemList.insert(END, dataInsert.upper())
    dataEntry.delete(0, END)

def deleteData():
    dataSelect = itemList.curselection()
    itemList.delete(dataSelect)

def clearData():
    itemList.delete(0, END)

def printData():
    dataDirectory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    f = open('items.txt', dataDirectory, 'ab+')
    f.write(bytes('', itemList.get(), 'UTF-8'))
    f.close()

def rootExit():
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.config(bg='gray79')
root.title('Inventory Recording Systems')
root.geometry('1300x800')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

mainLabel = Label(text='Inventory Recording Systems',
                  font=('comic sans ms', 20, 'bold'),
                  bg='gray79',
                  fg='black')

mainLabel.place(x=360, y=10)

f1 = Frame(root,
           bg='black',
           width=300,
           height=40)

f1.place(x=40, y=22)

f2 = Frame(root,
           bg='black',
           width=300,
           height=40)

f2.place(x=950, y=22)

dataLabel = Label(root,
                  text='Enter Data:',
                  font=('comic sans ms', 20, 'bold'),
                  bg='gray79')

dataLabel.place(x=10, y=130)

dataEntry = Entry(root,
                  font=('arial', 16, 'bold'))

dataEntry.place(x=250, y=142)

itemList = Listbox(root,
                    font=('arial', 15, 'bold'),
                    width=47,
                    height=16)

itemList.place(x=10, y=200)

addButton = Button(root,
                   text='Add Data',
                   font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
                   bg='gray89',
                   fg='black',
                   relief=GROOVE,
                   width=15,
                   height=1,
                   bd=5,
                   command=addData)

addButton.place(x=865, y=215)

deleteButton = Button(root,
                   text='Delete Data',
                   font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
                   bg='gray89',
                   fg='black',
                   relief=GROOVE,
                   width=15,
                   height=1,
                   bd=5,
                   command=deleteData)

deleteButton.place(x=865, y=345)

clearButton = Button(root,
                   text='Clear Data',
                   font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
                   bg='gray89',
                   fg='black',
                   relief=GROOVE,
                   width=15,
                   height=1,
                   bd=5,
                   command=clearData)

clearButton.place(x=865, y=470)

printButton = Button(root,
                   text='Print Data',
                   font=('arial', 20, 'bold'),
                   bg='gray89',
                   fg='black',
                   relief=GROOVE,
                   width=15,
                   height=1,
                   bd=5,
                   command=printData)

printButton.place(x=865, y=595)

exitButton = Button(root,
                   text='Exit',
                   font=('arial', 10, 'bold'),
                   bg='gray89',
                   fg='black',
                   relief=GROOVE,
                   width=6,
                   height=1,
                   bd=5,
                   command=rootExit)

exitButton.place(x=1212, y=752)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: give us the full error please. Also please include enough code so that we can reproduce your error, this gives a different error

Comment: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: I mean like the full Traceback, everything that's output. And please provide code so that it can be reproduced

Comment: Before it said it's mostly code xD

Comment: @Yoshix that's what we want to see...

Comment: PLEASE try the code you are posting before editing again, it gives a different error. Good luck with this

Comment: The code actually doesn't raise any errors for me...

Comment: I mean, try using the print button.

Comment: Yea, that gives me this error: `NameError: name 'filedialog' is not defined`

Comment: Try using tk.FileDialog or FileDialog

Comment: But it's your code you provided. Your code should just run as you've provided it.

Comment: Not on Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because your Print function tries to open a file in this format. The open function in os accepts filename, mode, buffer in that order.  This is what you have in your script:

```
f = open('items.txt', dataDirectory, 'ab+')
```

You are passing (file name, path, mode).  Instead, you should do something like this:

```
f = open(dataDirectory+'/items.txt', mode='a')
```

BTW, you will still have errors with how you are writing.  I'd suggest you read the documentation for os items and their use in Python 3.  Go to your terminal and run this:

```
import os
help(os)
```

Also, read this [article](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html), it will help you with migrating code from python 2 to 3 and will help you spot potential issues with migrations.  THe paragraph particularly interesting in your case is this one:

> As part of this dichotomy you also need to be careful about opening
>   files. Unless you have been working on Windows, there is a chance you
>   have not always bothered to add the b mode when opening a binary file
>   (e.g., rb for binary reading). Under Python 3, binary files and text
>   files are clearly distinct and mutually incompatible; see the io
>   module for details. Therefore, you must make a decision of whether a
>   file will be used for binary access (allowing binary data to be read
>   and/or written) or textual access (allowing text data to be read
>   and/or written). You should also use io.open() for opening files
>   instead of the built-in open() function as the io module is consistent
>   from Python 2 to 3 while the built-in open() function is not (in
>   Python 3 it’s actually io.open()). Do not bother with the outdated
>   practice of using codecs.open() as that’s only necessary for keeping
>   compatibility with Python 2.5.

Comment: Required argument 'flags' not found. I tried making a seperate function for these two, even creating an existing file, but none works. Just gives a non ending sequence of errors.

Comment: Correct. As mentioned you are going to have to refactor that whole print function. It looks like you are trying to use the old 2.7 way of opening and writing to a file.  Read the migration article I provided and figure out what needs to be updated.

Comment: Seems like I can't find my problem there. :(
Btw, I never used Python2, just sometimes come up with my own Python3 functions haha.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter encoding  has to be passed like this

This code need to be re-written as

```
f.write(bytes('', itemList.get(), 'UTF-8'))
```

as

```
f.write(bytes('', itemList.get(), encoding='UTF-8'))
```